# How to say "My old teacher"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

If you say "Mi profesor viejo," your indicating your teacher old age-wise. I was wondering how you indicate that your talking about a past teacher.

Comment: You can change the order "Mi viejo profesor".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use "[ex](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=ex)" or "[antiguo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=antiguo)".

> Mi antiguo profesor.
>
> Mi ex profesor.

Comment: I'm not sure if using "ex" adequately describes the thought. I would say "Mi Profesor cuando yo estudiaba en ..."

Comment: "Mi antiguo profesor" is just perfect. "Mi exprofesor" does not sound right, for the same reason that you would not say "mi exmaestro". "Exprofesor" would be correct in a different situation, for example: "un exprofesor de instituto fue detenido por descargarse pornografía infantil".

Answer (score 8):

Probably the literal translation is not the usual way.

> My old English teacher told me ...

```
Mi profesor de inglés del año pasado me dijo ...

Un profesor de inglés que tuve me dijo ...

Archibaldo, que fué mi profesor de inglés, me dijo que ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were referring to the previous, or immediately "past" teacher, I would say, "mi profesor anterior."

Comment: "Anterior" would mean "previous", as in "last teacher".

Comment: @JoulSauron: "A previous" teacher is by definition a "past" teacher. They both stand in contrast to "old" (in the sense of "not young.")

Comment: If you say "mi profesor anterior" it means "my last teacher".

Comment: @JoulSauron: If you say "last," then you mean "IMMEDIATELY" past, as opposed to way in the past, right?

Comment: Exactly, the previous one.